# How do I make the background of an image always black but keep the hand in the foreground and the coin

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have a python script that i want to use to detect the dimensions of hands. But unless you have a pure black background it does not work. How do i keep the background of the image to be pure black and keep the hand in the foreground?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opTNV.jpg)

```
from PIL import Image

# Open the image
im = Image.open('image.jpg')

# Convert the image to grayscale
im = im.convert('L')

# Set all pixels with a value less than 128 to 0 (black) and all pixels with a value greater than or equal to 128 to 255 (white)
im = im.point(lambda x: 0 if x < 128 else 255, '1')

# Save the converted image
im.save('image_bw.jpg')
```

Comment: Can you spacified what do you want. Because I am confused

Comment: @ALexBreak i want it to be more accurate. pure black background and keep the hand in the foreground, no noise

Comment: yeah so in general you want to remove bg and make it black if I understand

Comment: @ALexBreak yes and preferably keep the hand image as is

Comment: Do [any of these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bimage-processing%5D+remove+background) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple techniques of background removal. You can try doing:

1. Threshold values of the images that are a lover than some value (threshold value really depends on your image). Or use adaptive thresholding. [OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)
2. Morphological erosion (getting rid of small particles you have in the background) [OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/df6/tutorial_erosion_dilatation.html)
3. Having the threshold mask you can apply this mask on the real image (mask tends to be 0 or 1 value)

Comment: How do i do that? i am not a python developer

Comment: You have ready to use snippets in the documentation, just change from C++ to python